# how to hide the bottom navigation tab bar in flutter when using on tab tapped method

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the bottom navigation tab bar in flutter and if we click on tab it navigate to another screen .here i am using on tab tapped method and also assign the current index to index, but when i was tapped on icon it navigates the screen with bottom navigation tab , i want to hide the tab when click on the tab`

```
 int _currentIndex = 0;
```

final List _screens = [

```
new HomeTab(),
new Loginpage(),
new HomeTab(),
new CartTab(),
new HomeTab(),
```

];

```
return Scaffold(


  body:
  _screens[_currentIndex],

  bottomNavigationBar: isBottomBarVisible ?  new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
      onTap: onTabTapped, // new
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Home")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.search), title: new Text("Search")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.notifications_none), title: new Text("Notifications")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_basket), title: new Text("Bag")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.person_outline), title: new Text("Account"))
      ]): Container(

  ),

);
```

}

```
 void onTabTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _currentIndex = index;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by using a boolean flag to track the visibility of the bottom bar and then use this flag to add it or not to the widget tree:

```dart
    bool isBottomBarVisible = true;

...
...

    bottomNavigationBar: isBottomBarVisible ? new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
      onTap: onTabTapped, // new
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text("Home")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.search), title: new Text("Search")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.notifications_none), title: new Text("Notifications")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_basket), title: new Text("Bag")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.person_outline), title: new Text("Account"))
      ]) : Container(),
```

If `isBottomBarVisible` is true, the `BottomNavigationBar` is added to the widget tree, otherwise the added widget is a void `Container`.
So you can handle the visibility of the `BottomNavigationBar` by setting `isBottomBarVisible` to true when the `onTabTapped` method is called.